# Using static within an enum

Tags: c#, enums, keyword, enumeration, reserved-words

Is it possible to use 'static' within an enum as such:

```
private enum pdfMode
{
   generate,
   static
}
```

Obviously 'static' is a key word.

It would be nice as I have a pdfMode which is indeed referred to within the app as 'static'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possibility is to use `Generate` and `Static` inside the enum. IMO uppercase looks best there anyway.

Comment: Plus, it's consistent with the recommended naming guidelines!

Answer (score 18):

To use a keyword as an identifier use the @ symbol:

```
@static
```

But using Pascal case is advisable here.

```
private enum PdfMode
{
   Generate,
   Static
}
```

See the [Enumeration Type Naming Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x252001.aspx):

> Use Pascal case for Enum types and value names.

Answer (score 6):

You can escape the keyword using `@`, like this:

```
private enum pdfMode
{
    generate,
    @static
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, its value in the enum is '@static', not 'static'

Comment: @w69rdy, not true; it's just that whenever the C# language refers to it, an @ symbol is necessary. If you used it from another CLR language where `static` was not a reserved word, you would just refer to it as `pdfMode.static`

Comment: @w69rdy, since the OP is using a case that is not the standard I assume is using `ToString` on the enumeration and wants it to output "static" which it does. The `@` is only relevant when used in C# code.

Comment: @Domenic Ah ok, still kinda defeats the point a bit if you have to refer to it in C# as '@static' and not simply 'static'!

Answer (score -2):

```
private enum PdfMode
{
   PdfMode_Generate,
   PdfMode_Static
}
```

so as not it conflict with

```
private enum xxxType
{
   xxxType_Moving,
   xxxType_Static
}
```